# Woocommerce 'recent products' assistance

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using the shortcode `[recent_products per_page="3" columns="3"]` in one of my pages.

I am unable to edit this page in the mytheme/woocommerce/content-widget-product.php page but any changes I am making are not getting applied. Am I editing the correct file? Is there a way to edit how this shortcode displays that I do not know about?

Any assistance to resolve this issue is appreciated.

```
<?php global $product; ?>
<li>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( $product->id ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_title() ); ?>">
        <?php echo $product->get_image(); ?>
        <span class="product-title"><?php echo $product->get_title(); ?></span>
    </a>
<?php if ( ! empty( $show_rating ) ) echo $product->get_rating_html(); ?>
<?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?>
</li>
```

This is the code that I am trying to edit - to no avail.

Comment: You should definitely be able to change this template. A couple things to check. 1) Doublecheck which file you are actually editing. It's not uncommon to have an IDE that doesn't show the full file path and trick someone into thinking they are editing their own custom override, when they are actually editing the base template file (which does not load if an override is present). 2) If you have verified that you are indeed editing the override file, try temporarily editing the base file instead. If you see changes there, you probably have a file name or directory issue.

Comment: Also, even though you may be triggering this shortcode in a widget, the actual function that builds the shortcode output is in /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-shortcodes.php, in a public function called recent_products(). This makes a call to the content-product template directly, and that's possibly where you need to look instead.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you update the files on server.

If you bought the template, probably you haven't access to the code of that widget.

Anyway, I think you are editing the wrong file.
Show some code please

Comment: Please check if you updated the files on server or in your localhost

Comment: I use WAMP to dev before pushing sites live. The files are being edited. I have updated the questions to have the code in question included.